# How to compare two rows from different tables and show the table values if the rows match?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two different tables. One is `person` and the other one is `Cardholder`. Both of these tables have one row with the similar name and same value and its called `personId`. What I am trying to do is compare the row `personId` on the `person` table to `personId` on the Cardholder table and print only rows that match the value of `personId` on both tables. How would I write in PHP to do such task? I tried few things but failed to do what I intend.

Comment: its called a **join** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: yes, this is a pure SQL question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql query would look something like this :

SELECT P.* FROM person P 
   INNER JOIN Cardholder C ON C.personId=P.personId

this would only select the fields from the table person that has a match on personId in the Cardholder table.

Answer (score 0):

You will need code like this one

MySQL Code: -

```
("SELECT Cardholder.personId, person.personId FROM Cardholder INNER JOIN person ON Cardholder.personId = person.personId");
```

PHP Code: -

```
if (count($SQLstatment) > 0) {Exist} else {Not}
```